# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) when setting up cocoapods environment

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am setting the cocoapods dependency management tool for iOS project, when building my project i got this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using `Xcode 4.5` and `Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4`. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet, so posting as an answer.

It would help to have a bit more information on what you did to setup cocoapods, library settings in XCode and whether this is your first time using cocoapods or if the issue suddenly started. Try to give us a good idea of the details of your current situation.

For the time being, a little googling popped up this URL: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/155

You might find it helpful, specifically the post near the bottom:

> In my environment the issue was that the Pods project did not have a
>   target called ADHOC (as per the main project). I duplicated the Pods
>   release target, called it ADHOC, changed the OS Deployment Target to
>   my requirement (5.0) and then everything worked.